# orthogonal inequality characterization question.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $E$ euclidian subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Show that if there exist a real number $a$ such that $\forall y \in E, \, x.y \leq a$, then $x \in E^{\perp}$.

The result can be easily proved if $a=0$, using a symmetry argument: since $x.y \leq 0$ holds for any $y \in E$, then $x.(-y) \leq 0$. As $x.(-y) = -x.y$ we obtain $x.y = 0$ and therefore $y \in E^{\perp}$.  However, I struggle to extend the argument when $a$ is not $0$. Any suggestion?

Comment: Scalar multiples of $y$ will be in $E$. Use this and the bilinearity of the inner product to show that if $|a| > 0$ and $x \cdot y \neq 0$ then $a$ cannot be an upper bound.

Comment: @CyclotomicField understood, thanks: if $a < 0$ then $a \leq x.y \leq -a$  which is impossible. If  $a > 0$, then $x.(a+1)y \leq a$ cannot hold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CyclotomicField's hint is a good one.  Vector spaces are closed under scalar multiplication.  Hence if wlog there is $b\gt0$ such that there is $y\in E$ with $y\cdot x=b$, we get $cy\cdot x=cb\gt a$ for $c\gt a/b$, a contradiction.